# How can I even out the output of the sigmoid function?

Tags: normalization, sigmoid-curve

I'm applying a sigmoid function to an array of values but the output is very concentrated near 1 (i.e. 25th percentile is 0.999). I think this is because the input array takes on values that are quite large (e.g. 23).

This is the distribution of the input array:

[image: Distribution of input array]

And this is the distribution of the output from the sigmoid function:

[image]

What's the best way of evening out the distribution so that values are mapped more evenly across the 0-1 range?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips The data is private so afraid I can't share it here. However, I'll edit my question now and share some details about it!

Comment: Is it important that it be a sigmoid function or do you just want the data to reside between 0 and 1?

Comment: @einar It doesn't have to be a sigmoid function.

Comment: The values of the ecdf are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Does this solve your problem? If not, why?